# Data link level transmission

Tags: frame, router, transmission, data-link-layer

At the link level, responses about receiving frames go from one node to another, or a node is waiting for a response from a router, this router from another router, etc.?

Comment: Is this just asking what the data link layer does? There are plenty of questions about it and explanations at the NetworkEngineering sister site, [like this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74282/communication-at-the-datalink-layer).

Comment: @ExaltedToast I did not found an answer to my question here. I understand the relationship of the data link and network layers and I know how the packet travels through the network. I'm interested in how the response comes at the link level, if the nodes are in different networks.

Comment: If the devices are in different networks, then it's not a data link layer problem, it's a network layer problem. Data link protocols are defined for each area network, not between networks.